# Agrupar valores SQL por dois campos

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando agrupar uma tabela para poder fazer um count, mas estou tendo dificuldades.

A estrutura da tabela é a seguinte:

```
ID - NOME - IDADE - ESCOLARIDADE
1  - João -   15  - Ensino Fundamental Completo
2  - José -   25  - Ensino Fundamental Completo
3  - Mara -   13  - Ensino Fundamental Completo
4  - Joca -   50  - Ensino Fundamental Incompleto
```

Preciso agrupar e fazer uma contagem da seguinte forma, contar quantas pessoas com a idade entre 12 e 65 tem o ensino fundamental completo, quantas tem incompleto. O resultado da query na tabela mostrada seria:

```
0-12 - Ensino Fundamental Completo - TOTAL: 0
12-65 - Ensino Fundamental Completo - TOTAL: 3
0-12 - Ensino Fundamental Incompleto - TOTAL: 0
12-65 - Ensino Fundamental Incompleto - TOTAL: 1
```

Já tentei várias formas e nada deu certo. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Ah, escolaridade está em uma outra tabela, ela tem uma chave estrangeira também, mas não to colocando no select. Estou utilizando o PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer assim

```
SELECT CASE 
          WHEN IDADE <= 12 THEN '0-12' 
          WHEN IDADE BETWEEN 13 AND 65 THEN '13-65'
          WHEN IDADE > 65 THEN '66 ou mais'
       END AS FaixaEtaria,
       ESCOLARIDADE,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ID) TotalAlunos
FROM TBL_TABELA
GROUP BY CASE 
            WHEN IDADE <= 12 THEN '0-12' 
            WHEN IDADE BETWEEN 13 AND 65 THEN '13-65'
            WHEN IDADE > 65 THEN '66 ou mais'
         END, ESCOLARIDADE
```

Desta forma, se para uma das combinações `FaixaEtaria vs Escolaridade` não existirem alunos, essa combinação não irá ser representada no resultado final.

Para que todas as combinações sejam representadas necessitas de uma tabela auxiliar, com todas as categorias, que depois juntas/ligas aos resultados.

Algo assim, por exemplo:

```
SELECT Categorias.FaixaEtaria,
       Categorias.Escolaridade,
       COALESCE(TotalAlunos, 0) Total,
FROM (
     SELECT '0-12' FaixaEtaria, 'Ensino Fundamental Completo' ESCOLARIDADE UNION ALL
     SELECT '0-12',  'Ensino Fundamental Incompleto' UNION ALL
     SELECT '13-65', 'Ensino Fundamental Completo'   UNION ALL
     SELECT '13-65', 'Ensino Fundamental Incompleto' UNION ALL
     SELECT '66 ou mais', 'Ensino Fundamental Completo'   UNION ALL
     SELECT '66 ou mais', 'Ensino Fundamental Incompleto' 
) Categorias
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT CASE 
             WHEN IDADE <= 12 THEN '0-12' 
             WHEN IDADE BETWEEN 13 AND 65 THEN '13-65'
             WHEN IDADE > 65 THEN '66 ou mais'
          END AS FaixaEtaria,
          ESCOLARIDADE,
          COUNT(DISTINCT ID) TotalAlunos
   FROM TBL_TABELA
   GROUP BY CASE 
              WHEN IDADE <= 12 THEN '0-12' 
              WHEN IDADE BETWEEN 13 AND 65 THEN '13-65'
              WHEN IDADE > 65 THEN '66 ou mais'
            END, ESCOLARIDADE
) Totais
    ON Totais.FaixaEtaria = Categorias.FaixaEtaria
   AND Totais.ESCOLARIDADE = Categorias.ESCOLARIDADE
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Fica aqui o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/81e1b/5)